# Telnetting from one container to another fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ibm-mq, docker-network

I have created two containers(both using IBM db2 express-c as base image) containing IBM MQ on both.
 Container names:

1. container_1
2. container_2

MQM names

1. mqm1
2. mqm2

container_1 has Queue Manager mqm1 listening on port 1414

container_2 has Queue Manager mqm2 listening on port 1415

When I am telnetting from container_1 to container_2 on port 1415 it says connection refused. Similar error occurs while telnetting from container_2 to container_1. For example :

`docker exec -it container_1 telnet container_2 1415`

But if I change the port on which queue manager is listening, to any port number greater than 60000, I am able to telnet to the container on that port.

What is the reason that I am not able to telnet to container using port no 1415?

Comment: please post your docker-compose.yml file